# Record a VBA Macro to Format Series of Pivot Charts on Excel

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

So I've got a bunch of Pivot Charts that I need to format. I'm new to VBA but wanted to record a macro and then use that for each chart. In this code, I want to replace "Sheet 5" with the active chart. Can anyone help me out with that?

Here's the code as it stands:

```
Sub ChartUp()
' ChartUp Macro AddChartDetails Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate

ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).Select
Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Position = xlBottom
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 5").ScaleWidth 1.3668124563, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 5").ScaleHeight 1.3356401384, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromBottomRight

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your post correctly. So I have updated your Sub to  receive 2 parameters: `Sht As Worksheet` and `ChtName As String`.

**Recommendation**: I think it's better to stay away from `ActiveSheet` and instead referenced worksheet, like `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

I've added another `Sub TestChartUp()` just to test this solution.

Try the code below :

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChartUp(Sht As Worksheet, ChtName As String)

' ChartUp Macro AddChartDetails Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

Set ChtObj = Sht.ChartObjects(ChtName) 

With ChtObj
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"
    .Chart.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
End With

With Sht.Shapes(ChtName )
    .ScaleWidth 1.3668124563, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    .ScaleHeight 1.3356401384, msoFalse, msoScaleFromBottomRight
End With

End Sub

'================================================================

Sub TestChartUp()

Call ChartUp(ActiveSheet, "Chart 5") '<-- I preffer not to use ActiveSheet, but "Sheet1" , etc.

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**: Running the Sub below when actually selecting the Chart you want to format.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChartUp()

' ChartUp Macro AddChartDetails Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

Set Sht = ActiveSheet
Set ChtObj = ActiveChart.Parent

With ChtObj
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    .Chart.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
End With

With Sht.Shapes(ChtObj.Name)
    .ScaleWidth 1.3668124563, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    .ScaleHeight 1.3356401384, msoFalse, msoScaleFromBottomRight
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for response Shai. That code changes the same chart. I was hoping to be able to click on another chart, run the macro, and have the clicked-on chart formatted in the way I recorded.

Comment: OK, I'll add another option for you then, try code under **Edit 1**

Comment: Alright! This works -- thank you so much Shai. So how would I record this if I wanted to add more commands (change plot area color, change decimals, etc.)? Or is this something I would have to type manually?

Comment: You can record a macro, see the command and then modify it to fit this code

Comment: @TiDrizA please mark as answer as I think I've answered your post

Comment: Sorry Shai I'm new to StackExchange. I'm still working on the code. But thank you for help.